# Change the legend in highcharts heatmap to show instead of a color bar, a set of fixed icons with hide and show on click

Tags: highcharts, legend, heatmap

Is it possible to have the same feature that you get in Apache echarts. Refer to the following Apache echarts example in JS snippet, where the legend given by type:"piecewise" allows the user to hide on click particular color values. How can i get the same thing in Highcharts. The usual heatmap shows a bar legend, but I want the conventional legend that you see in line or bar charts. Thanks.

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

// prettier-ignore
const hours = [
    '12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
    '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a',
    '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
    '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'
];
// prettier-ignore
const days = [
    'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
    'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'
];
// prettier-ignore
const data = [[0, 0, 5], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 11, 2], [0, 12, 4], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 3], [0, 16, 4], [0, 17, 6], [0, 18, 4], [0, 19, 4], [0, 20, 3], [0, 21, 3], [0, 22, 2], [0, 23, 5], [1, 0, 7], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 13, 6], [1, 14, 9], [1, 15, 11], [1, 16, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 19, 12], [1, 20, 5], [1, 21, 5], [1, 22, 7], [1, 23, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 5, 0], [2, 6, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 8, 0], [2, 9, 0], [2, 10, 3], [2, 11, 2], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 9], [2, 14, 8], [2, 15, 10], [2, 16, 6], [2, 17, 5], [2, 18, 5], [2, 19, 5], [2, 20, 7], [2, 21, 4], [2, 22, 2], [2, 23, 4], [3, 0, 7], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0], [3, 7, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 0], [3, 10, 5], [3, 11, 4], [3, 12, 7], [3, 13, 14], [3, 14, 13], [3, 15, 12], [3, 16, 9], [3, 17, 5], [3, 18, 5], [3, 19, 10], [3, 20, 6], [3, 21, 4], [3, 22, 4], [3, 23, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [4, 8, 0], [4, 9, 2], [4, 10, 4], [4, 11, 4], [4, 12, 2], [4, 13, 4], [4, 14, 4], [4, 15, 14], [4, 16, 12], [4, 17, 1], [4, 18, 8], [4, 19, 5], [4, 20, 3], [4, 21, 7], [4, 22, 3], [4, 23, 0], [5, 0, 2], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 0], [5, 5, 0], [5, 6, 0], [5, 7, 0], [5, 8, 2], [5, 9, 0], [5, 10, 4], [5, 11, 1], [5, 12, 5], [5, 13, 10], [5, 14, 5], [5, 15, 7], [5, 16, 11], [5, 17, 6], [5, 18, 0], [5, 19, 5], [5, 20, 3], [5, 21, 4], [5, 22, 2], [5, 23, 0], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [6, 3, 0], [6, 4, 0], [6, 5, 0], [6, 6, 0], [6, 7, 0], [6, 8, 0], [6, 9, 0], [6, 10, 1], [6, 11, 0], [6, 12, 2], [6, 13, 1], [6, 14, 3], [6, 15, 4], [6, 16, 0], [6, 17, 0], [6, 18, 0], [6, 19, 0], [6, 20, 1], [6, 21, 2], [6, 22, 2], [6, 23, 6]]
    .map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});
option = {
  tooltip: {
    position: 'top'
  },
  grid: {
    height: '50%',
    top: '10%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: hours,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: days,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  visualMap: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    calculable: true,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '15%',
    type: 'piecewise'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Punch Card',
      type: 'heatmap',
      data: data,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.7.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with Highcharts. You need to only use data-classes in color-axis settings.

```
  colorAxis: {
    dataClasses: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 50
    }, {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }],
    ...
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vk0t7g6n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/color-axis